# Style is not getting applied in React component when using class name inside module style sheet file

Tags: css, reactjs

**React Component**

```
import { useState } from "react";
import styles from "./input.module.css";

const Input = ({
  inputType,
  placeHolderText,
  headerText,
  footerText,
  titleText,
  size,
  ...props
}) => {
  const [isHover, setIsHover] = useState(false);
  const toggleHover = () => {
    setIsHover(!isHover);
  };

  const [isFocus, setIsFocus] = useState(false);
  const toggleFocus = () => {
    setIsFocus(!isFocus);
  };

  const outlineHoverStyle = {
    border: "3px solid blue",
    cursor: "default",
  };

  const outlineFocusStyle = {
    border: "thick double blue",
    cursor: "default",
  };

  const errorStyle = {
    border: "1px solid #D32F2F",
  };

  const normalBtnStyle = {
    borderRadius: "8px",
    border: "1px solid #828282",
  };

  const disabledStyle = {
    background: "#F2F2F2",
  };

  //Input Size
  const defaultSizeInput = {
    width: "200px",
    height: "56px",
  };

  const smallSizeInput = {
    width: "200px",
    height: "40px",
  };

  const largeSizeInput = {
    width: "250px",
    height: "66px",
  };

  const fullWidthInput = {
    width: "900px",
    height: "66px",
  };

  const multirowSizeInput = {
    width: "200px",
    height: "150px",
  };

  let inputStyle;
  switch (inputType) {
    case "hover":
      if (isHover) {
        inputStyle = outlineHoverStyle;
      } else {
        inputStyle = normalBtnStyle;
      }
      break;
    case "focus":
      if (isFocus) {
        inputStyle = outlineFocusStyle;
      } else {
        inputStyle = normalBtnStyle;
      }
      break;
    case "error":
      inputStyle = errorStyle;
      break;
    case "disabled":
      inputStyle = disabledStyle;
      break;
    default:
      inputStyle = normalBtnStyle;
      break;
  }

  let inputSize;
  switch (size) {
    case "small":
      inputSize = smallSizeInput;
      break;
    case "large":
      inputSize = largeSizeInput;
      break;
    case "fullwidth":
      inputSize = fullWidthInput;
      break;
    case "multirow":
      inputSize = multirowSizeInput;
      break;
    default:
      inputSize = defaultSizeInput;
      break;
  }

  return (
    <div className={styles.input}>
      <p className="titleText">{titleText}</p>
      <p className={`test ${inputType}`}>{headerText}</p>
      <input
        type="text"
        style={{ ...normalBtnStyle, ...inputSize, ...inputStyle }}
        onMouseEnter={toggleHover}
        onMouseLeave={toggleHover}
        onFocus={toggleFocus}
        onBlur={toggleFocus}
        placeholder={placeHolderText}
      />
      <p>{footerText}</p>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Input;
```

I'm trying to apply style to `1st and 2nd paragraphs` as below inside module style sheet file

**input.module.css** file

```
...

.titleText {
  width: 19rem;
  height: 0.75rem;
  font-size: 0.75rem;
  line-height: 0.75rem;
  color: #333333;
  font-family: Ubuntu Mono;
}

.test {
  color: red;
}

....
```

but I don't see any changes in UI ? I'm not sure where am I doing mistake ?

**Update**

I tried to populate className run time based on prop value but it doesn't work as expected

To get it working, it should show randomly generated className instead of `Styles.error`

[image]

Comment: I believe you have to use styles.titleText and styles.test instead of the literal text classnames

Comment: you're right, can you please add to the answer with details; I can accept the same.

Comment: If I wish to populate classname based on prop value isn't this the right way to do ?

Comment: You can pass "error" as prop and then apply the clasName as `className={styles[propKey]}`

Comment: Please add these 2 in separate answer section, so that I can accept them